# Tecla TAB navegar somente na MODAL

Tags: razor, modal

Bom dia Galera,

Preciso fazer com que a tecla TAB navegue somente na modal, um exemplo é o Twitter que quando a Modal mensagem está aberta ou qualquer outra, não conseguimos navegar na tela por trás através do TAB, alguém tem ideia de como isso é feito?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Você pode usar a propriedade tabindex="-1"

```
<div class="modal fade" id="modal" tabindex="-1">
    <div class="modal-dialog">
        <div class="modal-content">
            <div class="modal-header">
                <button hidden="hidden" type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close"><span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span></button>

            </div>
            <div class="modal-body">
                modal texto
            </div>
            <div class="modal-footer">
                <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">OK</button>
            </div>
        </div><!-- /.modal-content -->
    </div><!-- /.modal-dialog -->
</div><!-
```

Comment: Perfeito! Deu certo!!!